# Validar un input antes de pasar al siguiente elemento

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un acordeón en html con dos desplegables, necesito ayuda para validar cada campo en el paso uno.

1. En el primer paso tengo tres inputs
2. El segundo paso esta bloqueado y se habilita cuando el usuario llena todos los campos.
3. Como puedo agregar un borde rojo con css y javascript a los inputs si el usuario hace clic en el paso 2 sin antes llenar el paso
4. Como puedo agregar mi clase error-border, para decirle al usuario que debe llenar los datos antes de pasar al paso 2
5. Gracias por su ayuda de antemano

---

```
<style>
output {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0fr;
    transition: grid-template-rows 0.125s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    min-height: 0;
}

.ocultar_check {
    display: none;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+output {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    display: grid;
    gap: 0.2rem;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-inline: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.pasos {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: #1E1E1E;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.125s;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;

    &:hover {
        background: oklch(0.8 0 0.1);
    }
}

.error-border {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<fieldset id="accordion">
    <label for="1" class="pasos">Paso 1</label>
    <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="1" value="1" checked>
    <output>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="nombr" id="name" name="" required />
            <input placeholder="apellido" id="last_name" name="" required />
            <input placeholder="telefono" id="phone" name="" required />
        </div>
    </output>
    <label for="2" class="pasos">Paso 2</label>
    <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="2" value="2">
    <output>
        <div>
            <p>TEXTO</p>
        </div>
    </output>
</fieldset>

<script>
const accordion = document.getElementById("accordion");
const inputs = accordion.querySelectorAll("input");

    const firstNameInput = inputs[0];
    const lastNameInput = inputs[1];
    const phoneInput = inputs[3];

    const isStep1FilledIn = () => {
        return firstNameInput.value.trim() !== "" && lastNameInput.value.trim() !== "" && phoneInput.value.trim() !== "";
    };

    const disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn = () => {
        const steps = accordion.querySelectorAll(".pasos");

        if (!isStep1FilledIn()) {
            steps.forEach((step) => {
                step.classList.add("disabled");
            });
        } else {
            steps.forEach((step) => {
                step.classList.remove("disabled");
            });
        }
    };

    const preventClick = (e) => {
        if (!isStep1FilledIn()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };

    const enableClick = (step) => {
        step.addEventListener("click", preventClick);
    };

    const disableClick = (step) => {
        step.removeEventListener("click", preventClick);
    };

    const steps = accordion.querySelectorAll(".pasos");
    steps.forEach((step) => {
        enableClick(step);
    });

    firstNameInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
        disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn();
        if (isStep1FilledIn()) {
            enableClick(steps[1]);
        } else {
            disableClick(steps[1]);
        }
    });

    lastNameInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
        disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn();
        if (isStep1FilledIn()) {
            enableClick(steps[1]);
        } else {
            disableClick(steps[2]);
        }
    });

    phoneInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
        disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn();
        if (isStep1FilledIn()) {
            enableClick(steps[1]);
        } else {
            disableClick(steps[2]);
        }
    });

    disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira, te dejo un código que hace *más o menos* lo que pides. Quité un resto de lógica duplicada o repetitiva, como el hecho de declarar uno por uno los listeners para cada input del paso uno, o bien enumerarlos manualmente.

Eso no se hace así: a veces hay que trabajar un poco más para trabajar menos en el largo plazo. En este caso particular, me hice una función que trae todos los inputs hijos de un selecto

```
   const getRequiredInputs=(stepSelector)=>Array.from(
        stepSelector.querySelectorAll(
             "input[required],select[required],textarea[required]"
        )
   );
```

Con eso, cada vez que quiero recorrer los hijos de un grupo output sólo tego que hacer, por ejemplo

```
    for(let input of getRequiredInputs(step1)) {
       ...
    }
```

Y eso permite limpiar bastante el código.

```js
const accordion = document.getElementById("accordion");
const inputs = accordion.querySelectorAll("input"),
  paso1_group = document.getElementById("paso1_group"),
  paso2_group = document.getElementById("paso2_group");

const firstNameInput = inputs[0];
const lastNameInput = inputs[1];
const phoneInput = inputs[3];

const getRequiredInputs = (stepSelector) => Array.from(stepSelector.querySelectorAll("input[required],select[required],textarea[required]"));

const checkValidity = (stepSelector) => {
  let requiredInputs = getRequiredInputs(stepSelector);

  let invalid_quantity = 0;
  for (let input of requiredInputs) {
    input.classList.remove("invalid");
    if (!input.checkValidity()) {
      input.classList.add("invalid");
      invalid_quantity++;
    }
  }
  return invalid_quantity === 0;
};



const disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn = (stepSelector, previous_step) => {
  // inputs inside the stepSelector, not its predecessor
  let requiredInputs = getRequiredInputs(stepSelector);

  if (checkValidity(previous_step)) {
    previous_step.classList.add('complete')
    stepSelector.classList.remove('click_prevented');
    requiredInputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.removeAttribute("disabled");
      input.classList.remove("disabled");
    });
  } else {
    previous_step.classList.remove('complete')
    stepSelector.classList.add('click_prevented');
    requiredInputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      input.classList.add("disabled");

    });
  }
};
const requiredInputs = getRequiredInputs(paso1_group);
requiredInputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn(paso2_group, paso1_group);

  });
});



disableStepsIfStep1NotFilledIn(paso2_group, paso1_group);
```

```css
output {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition: grid-template-rows 0.125s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  min-height: 0;
}

.click_prevented {
  pointer-events: none;
}

input.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

output.complete label {
  background: #9C9 !important;
}

output.complete label::after {
  content: 'OK!' position:absolute;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.ocultar_check {
  display: none;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+output {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.2rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pasos {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: #1E1E1E;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #dddddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.125s;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  &:hover {
    background: oklch(0.8 0 0.1);
  }
}

.error-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="accordion">
  <output id="paso1_group">
  <label for="1" class="pasos">Paso 1</label>
  <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="1" value="1" checked>
  
        <div>
            <input placeholder="nombr" id="name" name="" required />
            <input placeholder="apellido" id="last_name" name="" required />
            <input placeholder="edad" type="number" id="edad" min="18"  required />
        </div>
    </output>
  <output id="paso2_group">
  <label for="2" class="pasos">Paso 2</label>
  <input class="ocultar_check" type="radio" name="toggle" id="2" value="2">
  <output id="paso2_group">
        <div>
             <input placeholder="profesion" id="profesion" name="profesion" required />
            <input placeholder="estado civil" id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil" required />
            <input placeholder="nacionalidad" id="nacionalidad" name="nacionalidad" required />
        </div>
    </output>
</fieldset>
```

Ojo: un elemento nativo `<form>`  tiene métodos `checkValidity` y `reportValitidy`, que aplican sobre todos sus elementos hijos, y funciona no sólo para asegurar que los elementos `required` estén completos, sino también para verificar que elementos con constraints de rango (sliders y número con `min` o `max`, casillas de texto o correo con restricción pattern, etc).

Estos mismos métodos están disponibles en todos los inputs, por lo que me pareció más flexible usarlos en vez de comprobar en duro usando su  `value`.

Sin ir más lejos, me tomé la libertad de modificar tu formulario. Ahora el tercer campo no es teléfono sino edad, y no basta con que tenga datos: la edad debe ser mayor a 18 para pasar al grupo 2. Es un ejemplo más ilustrativo de cómo funciona la validación del lado del cliente.

(lamentablemente un div no tiene tal método como para evitarnos la validación uno a uno)